# React router, отоброжение одного компонента на нескольких роутах

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Есть несколько страниц на которых один компонент отображается одинаково. Как это реализовать ?

Сейчас мы протсо вставляем этот компонент несколько раз для каждого роута, выглядит примерно так:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path=":ds" component={Side} />
    <Route path="/tables/:id" component={Side} />
</Router>
```

Вопрос, это правильно ? Может быть можно как то в path передать например массив урлов `path={[':ds', '/tables/:id']}` что бы роутер не перерендеривал этот компонент ?

Answer (score 1):

В React Router 4 можно использовать регулярку:

```
<Route exact path="(:ds|\/tables\/:id)" component={Side} />
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/391#issuecomment-294237556